# node.js multer Route.post() callback

Tags: node.js

I get and Error after changing `node multer` version.

This happened when I changed to version 1.4.0 from multer version 0.1.8

```
router.post('/uploadImage',  multer({
  dest:config.profilePath,
  rename: function (fieldname, filename, req, res) {
    return filename
  }
}), controller.uploadImage);
```

This is the error message:

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object
>   Object]

What's the problem?

Comment: What is `controller.uploadImage`? Is it a function? Have you set its export correctly?

Comment: exports.uploadImage = function(req, res){
  var item = req.files.file,
    filetype = item.extension,
    filesize = item.size,
    filename = item.name;
    res.json({ test: 0, message: 'Completed',file_name:filename,file_size:filesize, file_type:filetype});
}; 
The source is the same and I have already brought the version out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify how you want to handle the file upload in multer 1.4

https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts

There are few options

> `.single(fieldname)`
>
> Accept a single file with the name `fieldname`. The single file will be stored in `req.file`.
>
> `.array(fieldname[, maxCount])`
>
> Accept an array of files, all with the name `fieldname`. Optionally error out if more than `maxCount` files are uploaded. The array of files will be stored in `req.files`.
>   `.fields(fields)`
>   Accept a mix of files, specified by `fields`. An object with arrays of files will be stored in `req.files`.
>
> `.none()`
>
> Accept only text fields. If any file upload is made, error with code "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE" will be issued.
>
> `.any()`
>
> Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

You could try `.any()` for now, and see if it works. 
Then check out other options that might fit your project more appropriately.

```
let upload = multer({
  dest:config.profilePath,
  rename: function (fieldname, filename, req, res) {
    return filename
  }
});

// calling .any() to accept all files
router.post('/uploadImage', upload.any(), controller.uploadImage);
```